# How do I replace entire html with another html (Angular 2)

Tags: html, angular

**app.component.ts**

```
<div>
<app-head></app-head>
<app-body></app-body>
</div>
```

**head.component.ts**

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-head',
  templateUrl: './head.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./head.component.scss'],
  providers: []
})
...
```

**body.component.ts**

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-body',
  templateUrl: './body.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./body.component.scss'],
  providers: []
})
...
```

So the pages loads with content head + body but now I wanted to route to a different page and replace entire existing page with the new page. How do I do that?

In my app.module.ts I have the following...

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'newPage', component: NewComponent}
]
```

I wanted use when clicked a button to be redirected to this page and replace existing `<app-head>` and `<app-body>` is this possible?

If I just use below I still see the current `<app-head>` and `<app-body>`

```
<button type="button" (click)="loadNewPage()" >
```

**body.component.ts**

```
 loadNewPage() {
    this.router.navigate(['/newPage']);
  }
```

The results give me the current page.... and  doesnt really apply since I am not concating the contents together. I want to replace the head.html and body.html with newpage.html from the NewComponent.ts

Comment: what is the content of the NewComponent?

Comment: for testing I just use <p> Hello World </p>

Comment: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is what you need!

Comment: it does not print it but the url changes

Comment: As @callback suggested, use **router-outlet**. Described in [Angular router](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace the content in AppComponent with a router-outlet component and move that replaced content to a new component such as HomeComponent.  Use the HomeComponent in your default route so it will load when you initially visit the site.

It's probably best if you check the documentation for [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-outlet) since this is a pretty fundamental topic in Angular and there are a lot of details you should learn before you get too far.

App.component.html

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

home.component.html

```
 <div>
     <app-head></app-head>
     <app-body></app-body>
 </div>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
  { path: 'newPage', component: NewComponent}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to put a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your app component and move what's in your current app component to a new component. Then update your routes to:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: TheStuffYouMovedComponent },
  { path: 'newPage', component: NewComponent }
]
```